# JXMapKit drawing route with getGpxTrack()

Tags: java, dictionary, routes

I am trying to draw a route over the road using the source code below:

```
final List<GeoPosition> region = new ArrayList<GeoPosition>();

Painter<JXMapViewer> lineOverlay = new Painter<JXMapViewer>() {

public void paint(Graphics2D g, JXMapViewer map, int w, int h) {
  region.add(new GeoPosition(5.42031,100.34389));
  region.add(new GeoPosition(5.41984,100.33924));
  region.add(new GeoPosition(5.42300,100.33456));


  g = (Graphics2D) g.create();
  //convert from viewport to world bitmap
  Rectangle rect = jXMapKit1.getMainMap().getViewportBounds();
  g.translate(-rect.x, -rect.y);

  //do the drawing
  g.setColor(Color.RED);
  g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
  g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));

  int lastX = -1;
  int lastY = -1;
  for (GeoPosition gp : region.getGpxTrack()) 
  {
     //convert geo to world bitmap pixel
     Point2D pt = jXMapKit1.getMainMap().getTileFactory().geoToPixel(gp, jXMapKit1.getMainMap().getZoom());
     if (lastX != -1 && lastY != -1) {
        g.drawLine(lastX, lastY, (int) pt.getX(), (int) pt.getY());
     }
     lastX = (int) pt.getX();
     lastY = (int) pt.getY();
  }
  System.out.println("I am here");
  g.dispose();

   }


   };
```

However, I get an error at the line region.getGpxTrack().
I try to use the region only GeoPosition gp : region, it only draw a line between two points. What I want is a road route. Anyone know where I got wrong?

Comment: No method getGpxTrack() found. I think it suppose to include in the GeoPositiion library, but it din have.

Comment: Ah, ok but this is clear. You are trying to call `getGpxTrack()` on `java.util.List`. This is not possible cause `List` dosen't have this method.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I did the same to see if it works if you replace `region.getGpxTrack()` with  `region` as I assume in comment. Yes it works. Here is full worked application with that what you are trying to do:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMapKit;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMapKit.DefaultProviders;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMapViewer;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.mapviewer.GeoPosition;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.painter.Painter;

public class Starter {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {    
        final JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(500, 300);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JXMapKit jXMapKit1 = new JXMapKit();
        jXMapKit1.setDefaultProvider(DefaultProviders.OpenStreetMaps);
        jXMapKit1.setCenterPosition(new GeoPosition(5.41984, 100.33924));
        jXMapKit1.setZoom(3);

        final List<GeoPosition> region = new ArrayList<GeoPosition>();
        region.add(new GeoPosition(5.42031, 100.34389));
        region.add(new GeoPosition(5.41984, 100.33924));
        region.add(new GeoPosition(5.42300, 100.33456));

        final Painter<JXMapViewer> lineOverlay = new Painter<JXMapViewer>() {

            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics2D g, final JXMapViewer map, final int w, final int h) {
                g = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                // convert from viewport to world bitmap
                final Rectangle rect = jXMapKit1.getMainMap().getViewportBounds();
                g.translate(-rect.x, -rect.y);

                // do the drawing
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));

                int lastX = -1;
                int lastY = -1;
                for (final GeoPosition gp : region) {
                    // convert geo to world bitmap pixel
                    final Point2D pt = jXMapKit1.getMainMap().getTileFactory().geoToPixel(gp, jXMapKit1.getMainMap().getZoom());
                    if (lastX != -1 && lastY != -1) {
                        g.drawLine(lastX, lastY, (int) pt.getX(), (int) pt.getY());
                    }
                    lastX = (int) pt.getX();
                    lastY = (int) pt.getY();
                }

                g.dispose();

            }

        };

        jXMapKit1.getMainMap().setOverlayPainter(lineOverlay);

        f.setContentPane(jXMapKit1);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: When I use region only, I only get to draw a line between 2 points. What I want is a road route that use by car. Any ideas how to do that? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Now it makes route. You have to initialize your `region` outside of `paint` method. Otherwise it will add the same GeoPositions each time again and again if paint is called :) Now it makes routes like you would like to have.

Comment: I am following your step, and yet it only give me straight line that connect all the points. If that any others way to get a road route? thanks!

Comment: yes, you will get line between all points that are in `ArrayList`. I thought that was your aim

Comment: Actually I want to draw a route that can follow by car. Not just a straight line that cut across all the building. I think the getGpxTrack method is to the gps coordinate of every point, from a destination to next, so can form a route. But I found no information related to this method online. By the way, I had another question. I am adding waypoint into my maps using painter method, and then i draw the line using painter method as well. When I called this two method, the second one always override the first one, so I always get to show only one of it. Any idea how can I make it show both? tq

Comment: Here is no method called `getGpxTrack`. You can create one by your self. I think you have mixed here two thinks. Your question was about code that should draw a route on map. You have add a GeoPoints by your own. This is solved now. Second thing is how to get a gpx route.  But this is from my point of view not related to this question. To the second question: Yes it will override. But you can draw waypoints and route in `paint` method, then you have both in your map.